# To select Text from multiple TextViews

Tags: android

How to Select Text from multiple Text Views in android?

I have tried the below code which works fine for one text view at a time only. I want to copy text from many text views at one stretch.

```
  android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Comment: I want copy paste functionality across many text views at the same time.

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that at the same time. You need to set all text in a single text view.

Comment: I know that.But for my requirement is there any library or any open class available?

Comment: You can provide a button to do that; or long click.

Comment: But I wanted a selector which moves across many text views and helps to select and then copy.

Comment: Put a view over all the textview; then fake the selection based on gesture received on it

Answer (score -1):

Do In this Way.

Select on edittext at the time of Copy It automatically paste that portion of data in another Edittext.

After copying from all You simply get You want in that edittext.

Comment: Can you move across multiple edit text at one stretch to select the text as whole?

Comment: I want to select text from many text views or even edit text at one stretch.